# Setuptools Entry Point Formatting Guide

Tags: python, setuptools

Is there somewhere that explains all the kinds of variations that one can use in formatting entry points in the setup function of setuptools?

I've seen a few variations:

From [python paste](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/#id19):

```
entry_points={
    'paste.app_factory': [
        'main=myapp.mymodule:app_factory',
        'ob2=myapp.mymodule:ob_factory'],
    }
```

From [pylons](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pylons-webframework/en/latest/advanced_pylons/entry_points_and_plugins.html#creating-plugins):

```
entry_points="""
    [cms.plugin]
    jpg_image=image_plugin:make_jpeg_image_plugin
    png_image=image_plugin:make_jpeg_image_plugin
"""
```